# PHP FORM: Multiple Recipients based on Drop Down Selection

Tags: php, forms, header-injection

I need a form to send to multiple different receipients based off the user dropdown selection.  Here is what I've read up on so far...  I can get it to say success but I dont recieve the email.  Please help!!

Html:

```
<select id="sendto" class="css-select" name="sendto">
<option id="sales" value="gmail" name="sendto">Gmail</option>
<option id="support" value="yahoo" name="sendto">yahoo</option>
</select>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

$i = $_POST["sendto"];
switch ($i) {
case "gmail":
    $sendto = "gmail@gmail.com";
    break;
case "recpro":
    $sendto = "yahoo@yahoo.com";
    break;
default:
    $sendto = "gmail@gmail.com"; //opional
    break;
} 

function sanitize( $s ){
$injections = array('/(\n+)/i',
'/(\r+)/i',
'/(\t+)/i',
'/(%0A+)/i',
'/(%0D+)/i',
'/(%08+)/i',
'/(%09+)/i'
);
$s = preg_replace( $injections, '', $s );

return $s;
}  
//catch the posted data
$first_name = sanitize( $_POST['first_name'] );
$last_name = sanitize( $_POST['last_name'] );
$email = sanitize( $_POST['email'] );
$telephone = sanitize( $_POST['telelphone'] );

$body = $telephone."\n\n";
$body.= $first_name."<$email>";
$headers = "From: $last_name<$email>";

if(mail($send_to, $subject, $body, $headers)):
echo "success";
else:
echo "error";
endif;
?>
```

I need it to be header injection safe.

Comment: Have you tried `echo $send_to, $subject, $body, $headers` to see if variables all correct and have data? Also are you sending this from your web server or localhost?

Comment: I'll add echo.  Sending from web server.

Comment: added subject line $subject = "test email"; and if(mail($send_to, $subject, $body, $headers)):
echo "success", $sent_to, $subject, $body, $headers;

Comment: but the echo only shows "success, subject, $body,$headers" no email any ideas why the switch and $email_to isnt working?

Answer (score 0):

I just changed

`$i = $_POST["sendto"];
    switch ($i) {
    case "gmail":
    $sendto = "gmail@gmail.com";
    break;
    case "recpro":
    $sendto = "yahoo@yahoo.com";
    break;
    default:
    $sendto = "gmail@gmail.com"; //opional
    break;
    }`

to this

`$i = $_POST["sendto"];
    if ($i == "gmail"){
    $sendto = "gmail@gmail.com";
    }
    elseif ($i == "yahoo") {
    $sendto = "gmail@yahoo.com";
    }
    else
    {
    $sendto = "gmail@gmail.com";
    }`

and mail section to this:

`

```
$headers = "From: " . strip_tags($_POST['your-email']) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($_POST['your-email']) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

if(@mail($sendto, $subject, $mail_body, $headers)):
echo "success";
else:
echo "error";
endif;
```

`